# re building a json from an exciting one nodejs

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js

I've the current JSON that looks like this

```
      {
        "_id": "5371f7171b27d11418bd9b46",
        "name": "a",
        "length": 14
      },
      {
        "_id": "5371f7171b27d1143bd9b46",
        "name": "ab",
        "length": 3
      }
```

and I'm trying to get it to look like this one,

```
5371f7171b27d11418bd9b46: {
    name: "a",
    length: 14,
    toc: [] // in the future it will be in the json I get.
},
5371f7171b27d1143bd9b46: {
    name: "ab",
    length: 3,
    toc: []
}
```

this is what I tried,

```
var arrenged = {};
_.forEach(result, function(item) {
    arrenged[item._id] = arrenged[item._id] || {};
    arrenged[item._id][item.name] = arrenged[item._id][item.name] || {};
    arrenged[item._id][item.name].push(item);
    arrenged[item._id]['direction'] = 'rtl';
    arrenged[item._id]['toc'] = "[]";
});
res.jsonp(arrenged);
```

but I get TypeError: Object # has no method 'push', not sure what I'm doing wrong.
thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could just do:

```
var newObject = {};
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { //data is your current array of objects
    var id = data[i]._id;
    newObject[id] = {};
    newObject[id].name = data[i].name;
    newObject[id].length = data[i].length;
    newObject[id].toc = [];
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KWjb3/

Comment: well, I tried you're way like this http://pastebin.com/nv9RTktU but I dont get the out I want

Comment: @greW -- Remove this line: `arrenged[id] = id;`

Comment: @greW -- I posted a demo fiddle.

Comment: well, not I get: Cannot set property 'name' of undefined

Comment: @greW -- I updated the answer, I forgot a line - `newObject[id] = {};`